# Convert TSQL Query To Access

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access-2007, left-join

I like to covert this query to Access 2007.
Every time I try to run it, I get a Syntax Error Missing operator in query Expression.

I appreciate any help

```
SELECT     
u.UserID, 
u.FirstName, 
u.LastName, 
u.Username, 
u.Email, 
u.DisplayName, 
upd.TypeOfAccess, 
upd.kusfCompanyCode FROM dbo.dnn_Users AS u INNER JOIN
dbo.dnn_UserRoles AS ur ON u.UserID = ur.UserID INNER JOIN
dbo.dnn_Roles AS r ON ur.RoleID = r.RoleID AND (r.RoleName = N'KUSF Agent' OR r.RoleName = N'KUSF Company With Agent' OR r.RoleName = N'KUSF Company Without Agent') LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT     
    up.UserID, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ppd.PropertyName = 'TypeOfAccess' THEN up.PropertyValue ELSE '' END) AS TypeOfAccess,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ppd.PropertyName = 'kusf CompanyCode' THEN up.PropertyValue ELSE '' END) AS kusfCompanyCode
FROM
    dbo.dnn_UserProfile AS up INNER JOIN
    dbo.dnn_ProfilePropertyDefinition AS ppd ON 
    up.PropertyDefinitionID = ppd.PropertyDefinitionID AND ppd.PortalID = 0 
GROUP BY up.UserID) as upd on u.UserID = upd.UserID
```

Comment: As I recall, Access is a fan of the `RIGHT JOIN`. Are you hooking Access up to SQL Server? If so, why don't you use the designer...

Comment: I am not sure on how to recreate it in designer since the code seems to be hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this set of rules while converting TSQL query to Access 2007 query as outlined in the post. Probably it will help to solve your issue.

[Convert Microsoft Access (JET SQL) to SQL Server (T-SQL) Cheatsheet](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/30/Quick-Access-JET-SQL-to-T-SQL-Cheatsheet.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the info, that will be helpful in the future, but for now, I think I am making more errors trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

A few "problems" I'm seeing right off the bat:

1. Access SQL doesn't support `CASE`. Since both your `CASE` statements are two-valued, use `Iif(<condition>, <true_part>, <false_part>)`.
2. Access is *very* picky about having multiple joins set off in parentheses. Work "last to first", catching the last join in a set of parens (both table names--in this case your sub-select is one of them--the join between and the `ON` field(s)), then another closing paren after that, which opens just before the table name of the preceding join, &c. until you have all but the first table name (and first `JOIN`) enclosed in parens. (Don't be fooled though--this does *not* actually enforce an order of evaluation).
3. I think Access wants `LEFT JOIN` rather than `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but this might not matter.
4. Access may not support the "force to Unicode" `N'string'` operator. I've never used it, but won't actually swear that it's wrong (in context).
5. Access prefers double quotes to set off strings, rather than single. It *usually* accepts single quotes, though.

This may not solve your problem, but it may get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Access does indeed support `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Access IGNORES `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and treats it exactly the same as `LEFT JOIN`. Try it in the QBE -- you can write a JOIN with it and it will run fine. But save it and reopen it and the word `OUTER` is now gone.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought--why I said it might not matter.